# Styling React component with styles from frameworks

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styles, video.js

I'm trying to upload styles from another frameworks to my components in React. I didn't find info about this in videojs docs. At this moment I'm uploading styles via cdn like this:

```
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/6.3.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I'm uploading scripts locally, but how can I do that with styles? I'm using scss, so for my styles I'm using this:

```
require('.././styles/style.scss');
```

EDIT

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POPhJ.png)

Comment: Please post your project structure so we can help you with the paths

Comment: Okay, I uploaded my project structure

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing your code belongs to the index.html file (root path as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/POPhJ.png)

So you'll need to add your SCSS files like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/css" href="styles/contact.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/css" href="styles/desktop.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/css" href="styles/mobile.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/css" href="styles/other.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/css" href="styles/reset.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/css" href="styles/style.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/css" href="styles/tablet.scss">
```

Just after -or before- the other `<link>` tags